# Screen flickering Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu

How to solve it? Firstly, restart helped.
Now after several restarts, flickering persists.
Graphic card is NVIDIA 8500GT.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed proprietary drivers? If so, please edit your question and post the drivers version as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus) on installing latest NVIDIA drivers helped.

**Edit**. What really helped is disabling hardware acceleration in browser settings